# Prove that if $A \cap B = \emptyset$ and if dist($A,B$) = inf { $\rho (x,y) : x \in A$ and $ y \in B$ } then dist($A,B) > 0$.

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Suppose that $X$ satisfies the Bolzano- Weierstrass Property and that $A$ and  $B$ are compact subsets of $X$.

Prove that if $A \cap B = \emptyset$ and if dist($A,B$) = inf { $\rho (x,y) : x \in A$ and $ y \in B$ }

then dist($A,B) > 0$.

Show that even in  the space $R^2$ there exists subsets $A,B$ which are closed and satisfy  $A \cap B = \emptyset$, but dist($A,B)  = 0$.

**proof:**

Suppose that $X$ satisfies the Bolzano- Weierstrass Property and that $A$ and  $B$ are compact subsets of $X$.

Then there are subsequences $ x_{n_k}$ which converges to some $x$ as $k → \infty$ and similarly  $ y_{n_k}$ which converges to some $y$ as $k → \infty$  in $A$ and $B$ such that $\rho (x_{n_k},y_{n_k}) $ → dist($A,B)$

Since $A \cap B = \emptyset$, then $x \neq y$.

Thus dist($A,B) > 0$.

Is this correct? Can someone please give some feedback. Any help or better approach would really help. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The weakest point in your argument is when you say that $\rho (x_{n_k},y_{n_k}) \to dist(A,B)$. This step can probably be made rigorous, but I don't think it is absolutely immediate.

Here's an another way to do it:

Suppose, to deduce a contradiction, that $d(A,B)=0$. Since, for every $n$, $1/n>0$ and $d(A,B)$ is an infimum:  $$(\ast) \left ( \forall n \in \Bbb{N} \right ) \left ( \exists x_n \in A, y_n \in B \right )(0≤d(x_n,y_n)<1/n)$$

This furnishes two sequences $\{x_n\}$ and $\{y_n\}$. Since $A$ is compact, there exists a subsequence $\{x_{n_k}\}$ which converges to some $x \in A$. Applying the same reasoning to the subsequence $\{ y_{n_k} \}$ we obtain a subsequence $\{ y_{n_{k_j}} \}$ which converges to some $y \in B$. Now observe that:

$$(\ast \ast ) \,d(x,y)≤d(x,x_{n_{k_j}})+d(x_{n_{k_j}},y_{n_{k_j}})+d(y_{n_{k_j}},y)$$

Since $x_{n_{k_j}} \to x$ and $y_{n_{k_j}} \to y$, from $(\ast)$ follows that the three terms in the right hand side of  $(\ast \ast)$ can be made arbitrarily small, hence $d(x,y)=0$. But then $x=y$ and since $x\in A$ and $y \in B$ we get $x\in A\cap B$, which is absurd by our hypothesis.

For your statement in $\mathbb{R}^2$ consider $A=\left \{ (n,0) : n \in \Bbb{N} \right \}$ and $B=\left \{ (n,1/n) : n \in \Bbb{N} \right \}$.

Comment: Your approach is much clearer. Thank you for the help :)!

Comment: You're welcome :)